# Orientation should change only for the selected viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app, Four viewcontrollers navigates next by next in potrait mode, but i added coverflow in the final viewcontroller, and when the simulator is rotated it should go landscape.I selected all orientations in plist execpt the Upsidedown orientation, So that coverflow works fine in Landscape, but all the other viewcontrollers also goes to landscape when rotatad, but i need these viewcontrollers to be in potrait even the simulator is rotated.I tried many codes like,

```
    shouldAutorotate  and supportedInterfaceOrientations.
```

But i doesn't get a clear solution towards what iam expecting, if any ideas , will be thankfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new Objective-C class (subclass of UINavigationController) and add the following code to the .m files

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     NSLog(@"supportedInterfaceOrientations = %d ", [self.topViewController         supportedInterfaceOrientations]);

     return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
  {
     return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
  }

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions

    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
  }
```

After you added the new classes go to your ViewController classes and make the following changes

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate  // iOS 6 autorotation fix
  {
    return YES;
  }
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations // iOS 6 autorotation fix
  {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
  }

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation // iOS 6 autorotation fix
  {
      return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
  }
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
  {
      return YES;
  }
```

[image]

In the shouldAutorotate ,  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: return YES if you want the ViewController to be supporting Multiple orientation else return NO , also in houldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method pass the Orintation you want for that specific ViewController , Repeat the same for all the view controllers .

Reason of doing this:-

1:Although you can change the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: of any viewController to a specific orientation but since you are using the UINavigationController you also need to override the supportedInterfaceOrientations for your UINavigationController

2:In order the override the supportedInterfaceOrientations for UINavigationController we have subclassed UINavigationController and modified the method related to the UINavigation Orientation.

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Whether want to import that UINavigation Subclass to the view controllers in the viewcontrollers where i want to lock orientaion, bcoz it is same as before, not been changed after i created class as you preferred.

Comment: I forgot to mention that to need to change the class of your UINavigationController from default(UIBNavigationController) to the custom class that you have created (customNavigationController). Please see my updated answer .

Comment: Mine is based on StoryBoard, i not used any XIB files.

Comment: Updated my answer again , take reference from updated image in my answer .

Comment: Great, Its Working Fine,as i Expected, Thanks for saving my time, Please Keep in Touch..

Comment: @Arwin Dont forget to mark your question as answered if Gaurav's answered solves your problem.

Comment: Ya, Marked as Answered.Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add an observer to the viewDidLoad method of the view you want to rotate like this :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

and then set the views according the the landscape view inside the **orientationChanged** method like this :

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note{
UIDevice * device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
switch(device.orientation)
{
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:

        break;

    default:
        break;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 and later, the view controllers responsible for rotation are the container Viewcontrollers such as UINavigationController & UITabBarController . What are you using as the rootviewcontroller in your project??

I have navigation controller category written [here](http://buddingdevelopers.com/autorotation-in-ios/) in which you can handle the supported interface orientations for the individual view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad or viewWillApper method add following code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
```

set the orientation

```
#if (__IPHONE_6_0 >= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED)
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {


    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);


}
#endif

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: I tried yours, but its not working.Am i missing something.I added this function in App Delegate,                                                                     - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window

{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

Comment: Add this method in ViewController. And check which method call first appDelegate or ViewController.